# Load huge data (around 5000) in android AutoCompleteTextView efficiently

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have to load around 5000 data in an AutoCompleteTextView. If i load all the data directly inside adapter the application hangs.

So i refresh the adapter with matching 10 items on text changed. But still for each text change there is slight hicup as it queries db on every charcter.

Is there any better way to load 5000 data efficiently and fast ? .

```
buildFields();

AutoCompleteTextView field;
FilterableArrayAdapter typeAdapter;

public void buildFields() {
    refreshFieldData(null);
    field.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Log.d("log","selected");
        }
    });

    field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            String text = field.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            if(text.length() == 0){
                return;
            }
            refreshFieldData(text);

        }
    });

}



void refreshFieldData(String text){
    List<type> list;
    if (text != null)
        list = db.getInfoMatchingStr(text); //Returns the matching 10 digits
    else
        list = db.getInfo(); // Returns  10 digits

    typeAdapter = new FilterableArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item);
    typeAdapter.attachInfo(list);
    field.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
    typeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

delay the query by 500ms for example.

```
final static int query_msg=1
onTextChanged(){
    if(mHandler.hasMessage(1)){
        mHandler.removeMessage(1);
    }
    mHandler.sendDelayed(query_msg,500)
}
...
case query_msg:
     //do query action.
```

Comment: No this doesnt improve the speed

Answer (score 0):

How have you stored words inside your database. For efficiency you can store words based on dictionary structure that way you can filter results based on the first word entered by the user. Since you are using ten words at a time this should increase the efficiency a lot.